# Using soft assertion in cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, selenide

I am using cucumber with selenide, and when I add assertionMode = SOFT  in Selenide configuration and running scenario, then I am getting this error.

**You must configure you classes using JUnit4/JUnit5/TestNG mechanism as documented in https://github.com/selenide/selenide/wiki/SoftAssertions**

It seems I should use ErrorsCollector in the hooks for the before and after method.

I have driver setup in the hooks package and selenide capabilities in the before a method.

[image]

Could someone please tell me where and how to use ErrorsCollector?

Or is there something else?

Comment: How do you run your test? Which runner are you using? Also do you set up soft assertion in `openBrowser`?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I run my test via features files. 
Runner is TestRunner class:
(@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"hooks", "steps"},)
Soft assertion set up: assertionMode = SOFT

Answer (score 0):

Soft Assertion are present in the TestNG, so please add TestNG maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and
in code,

```
SoftAssert aa = new SoftAssert();
aa.assertEquals(true, true);
```

Comment: TestNg is used for test annotations, but in the Cucumber framework, tests are run via feature files.
Also in Selenide, you don't need to use assertEquals, condition is used in should constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running your tests with the help of `@RunWith` annotation I assume there is JUnit 4 under the hood.

So what you can try to do is to add this field

```java
@Rule 
public SoftAsserts softAsserts = new SoftAsserts();
```

to the class that is annotated with `@RunWith` annotation (`TestRunner` class).

Comment: @Rule not applicable to type in the TestRunner class

Comment: What does it mean? Is it an error message?

Comment: No idea. Rule annotation is not recognized properly, when I hover over it, get that message.